# Multiple Background Images issues in ie7/ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

I am trying to solve a bug in ie7/ie8 for multiple background images...

I know that in originally it doesn't support in ie's but i have googled some interesting stuff on web, for example, [Cross-Browser Multiple Background](http://www.pziecina.com/design/turorial_demos/multi_bg_images.php)

Basically it is of two images background but i want to have 3 images with the defined position and size of the images via css...
Fiddle code is not working in ie7/ie8...

http://jsfiddle.net/CsKhy/4/

Can anyone help??

Comment: Use CSS3 PIE to make this work on old browsers

Comment: I agree!  CSS3 PIE ( http://css3pie.com/ ) does wonders at giving IE some graceful degradation.  Be careful though with it - somestimes PIE will hiccup and the styles just won't show at all.  But really, Modernizr makes the most since unless its absolutely necessary for you to have multiple backgrounds on ie7/ie8.

Answer (score 2):

Use nested divs for a crossbrowser-compatible solution.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/CsKhy/5/

Note: `background-size` is not compatible in IE8 or lower, so maybe it's better using images instead of backgroundimages.

Comment: sorry but want minimum to minimum html to use in the document... The html is trying some actions with some JavaScript so i cnt afford touch the html part...

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
<style>
  .bgImage{width:100%;}
</style>
```

Right after the body tag and before any other code insert this

```
<img src="yourimage" class="bgImage"/>
```

Not ideal solution but is compatible and works, I have used it many times.  (make sure your image is a large image to begin with otherwise it will distort on larger screens)